# Can't link Kubernetes deployment to GitLab Environment page

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, gitlab, pipeline, environment

I'm trying to set up a full CI/CD pipeline for a SpringBoot application, starting from a GitLab repository (see https://gitlab.com/pietrom/clock-api) and automatically deploying to a Kubernetes Cluster backed by Google Cloud Platform.

My pipeline works quite fine (the app is built, it is packaged as a Docker image, the image is published on my project registry and containers are started for both `staging` and `production` environment), except for a detail: `Operation/Environments` page shows me both environments, with the following warning:

```
Kubernetes deployment not found
To see deployment progress for your environments, make sure your deployments are in Kubernetes namespace <projectname>, and annotated with app.gitlab.com/app=$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG and app.gitlab.com/env=$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.
```

I googled around a bit but I can't resolve this problem: my `deployment.yml` contains requested annotation, both for *deployment* and *pod*:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: clock-api-ENVIRONMENT
  annotations:
    app.gitlab.com/app: "PROJECT_PATH_SLUG"
    app.gitlab.com/env: "ENVIRONMENT"

spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ENVIRONMENT
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "8080"
        prometheus.io/path: "/actuator/prometheus"
        app.gitlab.com/app: "PROJECT_PATH_SLUG"
        app.gitlab.com/env: "ENVIRONMENT"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: clock-api-ENVIRONMENT
          image: registry.gitlab.com/pietrom/clock-api
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.gitlab.com
```

`PROJECT_PATH_SLUG` and `ENVIRONMENT` placeholder are substituded (using `sed`) during pipeline execution with values provided by GitLab infrastructure (`$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG` and `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG`, respectively) and I can see the expected values in my GCP console, but GitLab integration does not seem to work.

I'm missing something but I can't figure what differences there are between my deployment setup and the official documentation available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_boards.html).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What about namespace? Did you check it too?

Comment: I deploy on Kubernates using the project name (clock-api in my case) as the namespace value... Should I use any other value??

Comment: I tried with `--namespace $CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG` (i.e. `pietrom-clock-api` in my case), too, but the result is the same: everything in the pipeline works fine, but *Environment* page shows the *Kubernetes deployment not found* warning...

Comment: Does namespace itself exist on the cluster? Sometimes GitLab fails to create it, for example when cluster is added after project is created. See how they do it in AutoDevOps: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/691d88b71d51786983b823207d876cee7c93f5d4/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml#L506

Comment: Both `clock-api` and `pietrom-clock-api` namespaces exist (if not, the deploy should fail). Is it correct to deploy using `clock-api` namespace or should I use a different namespace?

Comment: You should use $KUBE_NAMESPACE as per the link I gave you above. This is pre-defined env var by GitLab, which is used by GitLab internally, including for Operations/Environment page. See more this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#deployment-variables

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! If you want write an answer with your suggestion, I'll accept it.

Comment: Answer posted! Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also an important part:

> make sure your deployments are in Kubernetes namespace

GitLab tries to manage namespaces in the attached Kubernetes cluster - creates a new namespace for every new GitLab project. It generates namespace from project name and project id.

Sometimes GitLab fails to create namespace, for example when cluster is added **after** project is created. It's probably a bug, and here is how they overcome it [in AutoDevOps](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/691d88b71d51786983b823207d876cee7c93f5d4/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml#L506):

```
  function ensure_namespace() {
    kubectl get namespace "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" || kubectl create namespace "$KUBE_NAMESPACE"
  }
```

This env var `$KUBE_NAMESPACE` - is defined by GitLab automatically, as well as many other Kubernetes-related variables:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#deployment-variables

Then GitLab relies on this namespace internally and uses for various UI pages of the project, including Operations/Environment. So if you follow their convention, and apply your Kubernetes deployment to this namespace, GitLab will see your application.

In our work we go one step further and at the beginning of a job even [set this namespace as the default](https://gitlab.com/softmill/template-gitlab-ci/blob/2656a064c8e92be0f93e036e0f74f79b39d8d1fb/.gitlab-ci-kube.yml#L128).

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace="$KUBE_NAMESPACE"
```

Then all further `kubectl` commands will by default use this namespace.